# "XDG0062 Catastrophic failure..". When trying to use UWP controls into a .Net Core WPF application. Why?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, xaml-designer, xaml-islands

Using:
- Visual Studio 2019 16.4.4 Version 4.8.03752.
- Project .Net Core 3.1 With WPF

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VCRTForwarders.140" Version="1.0.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PtdcFieldView\PtdcFieldView.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I receive an error from the XAML Designer :

> Catastrophic failure.
>
> WindowsXamlManager and DesktopWindowXamlSource are supported for apps
>   targeting Windows  version 10.0.18226.0 and later. Please check either
>   the application manifest or package manifest and ensure the
>   MaxTestedVersion property is updated.

Please note that Microsoft message is totally awkward because "MaxTestedVersion" is "maxversiontested" in project Manifest and it is, as far as I understand, the minimum version required.

With this code:

```
<Window x:Class="PtdcGui.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PtdcGui"
        xmlns:ptdcfieldview="clr-namespace:PtdcFieldView;assembly=PtdcFieldView"
        xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps;assembly=Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0"> <!--<maps:MapControl/>--> </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row ="1"> <controls:MapControl x:Name="MyMapControl" /> </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

**Question** :

- Why do I get an error from the XAML Designer although the code is compiling fine and running fine?
- Why I can't acces my control with it's name from code behind? **(This question if fixed, I had to reboot Visual Studio)**